# Need to set up local map tile cache - how to obtain full tile set?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, tilecache

I'm using the [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org/) Javascript library to provide a map view for my web app. This may be deployed in an environment where no external Internet access is possible. So ideally I need a full set of map tiles, pre-populated on a local web server. I'm assuming this is going to be a *lot* of data though.

Until now I've been using [TileCache](http://tilecache.org/) to fetch and store map tiles locally on disk. This is ok, but obviously only fetches tiles for the areas I explore on the map. Plus, this solution won't work for the said deployment environments if the relevant tiles for the target area aren't already in the local disk cache.

I don't really have a good idea of just how much data a full tile set would amount to, so is this idea completely impractical? Where would I obtain the tile set?